# Android 4.0 – any browser able to set UserAgent?

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, browser, user-agent-string

**Is there any browser (or its add-on) running on Android 4.0 where I can tweak UserAgent string?**

I would like to use older Android device to view Microsoft To-Do list in a browser. But they obviously have Android version check, because they display only old OWA (Outlook Web Access) interface.

Apps already tested:

- Samsung Internet - seeing the old Outlook UI (also in desktop mode)
- UC Browser - this app is unable to start
- Opera Mini - seeing the old Outlook UI

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After further research I found that [Dolphin Browser](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=mobi.mgeek.TunnyBrowser) has **User agent** setting built-in directly in its **Settings** screen, on tab **Advanced**.

In my specific case, switching the above setting to `Desktop` made the **Microsoft To-Do** web UI accessible as expected.